# Nuxt project output as UI plugin

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, single-page-application

How can I host spa project output in CDN and load it in  html page like a plugin ? For example Swagger UI can load from CDN and load UI in an HTML tag.

Currently I can do it manually by something like this

```
  const nuxtApp = document.createElement('div');
  nuxtApp.id = '__nuxt';

  document.querySelector(config.selector).appendChild(nuxtApp);
  [
    'http://cdn_link/_nuxt/runtime.XXXXX.js',
    'http://cdn_link/_nuxt/app.XXXXX.js'
  ].forEach(src => {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
  })
}
```

The above file I'd manually  created based on build output and then in my local html file I can do like this.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app"></div>
<script src="http://cdn_link/lib.js"></script>
<script >
  initApp({
    selector: '#app'
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any easier way to create the lib file along with the build of nuxt ?